# Generate an array of years with duplicates of each year + labeled season

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How do i dynamically generate an array of years starting from 2004 till the current year, with each year labeled with "Spring" and "Fall" like in the attached picture?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried and where are you facing a problem/issue?

Comment: I was only able to generate a list of years using for loop but trying to find the way to add seasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). If you don't care about the current year's season then you can get all results up to the current year.

```js
function generateArrayWithSeason(start) {
  return Array(new Date().getFullYear() + 1 - start)
    .fill("")
    .flatMap((_, i) => [`${start + i} SPRING`, `${start + i} FALL`]);
}

console.log(generateArrayWithSeason(2004));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want results according to current year's `spring` and `fall`

> spring runs from March 1 to May 31

> fall (autumn) runs from September 1 to November 30

```js
function generateArrayWithSeason(start) {
  const month = new Date().getMonth();
  let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const springMonths = [3, 4, 5];
  const fallMonths = [9, 10, 11];

  return Array(currentYear + 1 - start)
    .fill("")
    .flatMap((_, i) => {
      if (currentYear === start + i) {
        if (springMonths.includes(month)) return [`${start + i} SPRING`];
        if (fallMonths.includes(month)) return [`${start + i} FALL`];
      }
      return [`${start + i} SPRING`, `${start + i} FALL`];
    });
}

console.log(generateArrayWithSeason(2004));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why someone downvoted my answer even without telling the reason.

Comment: It may have been because your answer doesn't generate the current year's fall/spring (at the time of writing), or not include spring/fall when they haven't yet occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return an array of strings containing `"<year> <SPRING/FALL>"` starting from 2004 until the current date, not including the current year's spring or fall seasons if they haven't occurred.

```js
const seasons = {
  2: 'SPRING',
  8: 'FALL',
};
const now = new Date();
const output = [];
for (let current = new Date(2004, 2, 1); current <= now; current.setMonth(current.getMonth() + 6)) {
  output.push(`${current.getFullYear()} ${seasons[current.getMonth()]}`);
}
console.log(output);
```